# Convert Stream to Mono

Tags: java, java-stream, project-reactor

How retern Mono from stream, using streams limit?

1. Need get List from stream and check size elements

```
var personsResult = persons.getSomething().stream().limit(1).toList();
```

2. I want add  list to

```
Mono.just(personsResult)
```

I'm try

```
  Mono.just(persons.getSomething().stream().limit(1).toList();
```

It's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that `getSomething()` can return a `streamable` object, `limit(1)` will stream only the first value in that object.  To retrieve it, you can do the following:

```
var personsResult = persons.getSomething().stream().limit(1)
                   .findAny().get();
```

If the stream is empty, you will get an exception.  To return a default value for an empty stream you can do.

```
var personsResult = persons.getSomething().stream().limit(1)
                   .findAny().orElse(defaultValue);
```

Where defaulValue is of type `var`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your object is `Person`, I find no reason to leave a single object in `List<Person>` and then wrap again in `Mono<List<Person>>`. You can use the power of `Optional` to map into `Mono` resulting in flat `Mono<Person>`:

```
Mono<Person> mono = persons.getSomething()
        .stream()
        .limit(1)
        .findFirst()
        .map(Mono::just)
        .orElseGet(Mono::empty);
```

... or ...

```
Mono<Person> mono = Mono.justOrEmpty(
    persons.getSomething()
           .stream()
           .limit(1)
           .findFirst()
           .flatMap(Mono::just));
```

Answer (score 0):

You really want to get into `Publisher` land asap. The analog to a stream is a flux:

```
var single = Flux.fromStream(Stream.of("one", "two", "three"))
            .take(1)
            .single();
```